# Android - Show confirm dialog before deleting marker

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I'm developing an app using google maps api v2, and I have some markers. Using onInfoWindowClick, I delete the marker, but I would like to show a confirmation popup with "delete" and "cancel" buttons so that the user can confirm the deletion. Would that be possible? This is my code, and my problem is that I cannot access to "marker" inside "onClick":

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.deletelayout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(v);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
       //I cannot get access to the marker in here
    }});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

//marker.remove();
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {`

to
 `public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {`

you now should be able to access the marker variable in your `onClick`